# Не работает Header location

Tags: header, php

Вот код

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
session_set_cookie_params(604800000, "/", ".site.ru", false, false);
session_start();
define('SID',session_id());
if (!isset($_SESSION["uid"])){
echo "Хакирование запрещено!";
exit;
}
include('../conf.php');
$uid = intval($_SESSION["uid"]);
header ("Location: ../profile.php");
exit;
?>
```

А вот ошибка

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...general.php:16) in ...general.php on line 15
```

Пересохранял без BOM, как сам файл, так и конфиг, лишних пробелов и интеров нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайди в **php.ini** и установи следующее значение:

```
output_buffering = On
```

*P.S. Не забудь перезагрузить сервер, на котором установлен PHP. Наверное, это апач.*

Answer (score 1):

В самом начале

```
ob_start();
```

После всех действий в конце скрипта

```
ob_end_flush()
```

Это буферизует вывод (кроме заголовков). Все должно работать после этого.

Comment: ob_end_flush() обязательно писать?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, нет, можешь просто `ob_flush()`